# Open file after download completed

Tags: c#, file-io, download

The following code doesn't work, somehow I can't get the int value from the 'Completed' method to my btn_Start_Click method:

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int completedDownload = 0;      

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://somesite.com/file.jpg"), @"c:\file.jpg");

    if (Completed.completeDownload == 1)
    {
        //open the file code goes here.
    }

    //Rest of the code goes here.
    //and here
    //and here
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    completedDownload = 1;
}
```

Comment: "Async" means "happens later".  Move all the code you now have after the DownloadFileAsync call to the Completed method.  Beware that Completed is called by a threadpool thread, you'll need to use Control.BeginInvoke() to run any code that updates the UI.

Comment: @naaitsab could you please share the code for how to open the file after it's completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the remarks on the `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` function:

> The file is downloaded asynchronously using thread resources that are
>   automatically allocated from the thread pool. To receive notification
>   when the file is available, add an event handler to the
>   DownloadFileCompleted event.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx)

It seems like a better choice to fire a function when the file is completed would involve using an event handler. Here is an example using the `DownloadFileCompleted` handler:

```
// Sample call : DownLoadFileInBackground2 ("http://www.contoso.com/logs/January.txt");
public static void DownLoadFileInBackground2 (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called
    // when the download completes.
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback2);
    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
    client.DownloadFileAsync (uri, "serverdata.txt");
}
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Completed handler executes asynchronously. When you're checking on that int there is no warranty that hanlder has set the value. If you want to perform some action when download is complete, do it in the Completed method.

Comment: The "problem" is that I want to run all my code under 1 method namely "btn_Start_Click" so that isn't realy an option in my case.